# Defining field separator and text qualifier on the fly for CSV file

Tags: java, regex, csv, split

I am reading csv files which have comma(,) as field separator and double quotes(") as text qualifier. Following is the code to fetch columns of a row:

```
row.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")
```

which is working fine.
But I want to specify my field separator and text qualifier dynamically i.e they will be passed as input along with csv file. And file will be parsed as per the input filed separator & text qualifier. How can I modify the regular expression above to take field separator & text qualifier on the fly.

EDIT:
I am using Apache Commons CSV to parse csv files. But in my case header row can be any row in the file. And there is no way to pass header row index to Commons CSV parser. So I will read the file manually and fetch header row. Split its columns into a String array and pass it to parser. Plus field separator & text qualifier are user defined, so need to do the splitting on that basis.

Comment: Why not use http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ (or any other CSV lib) ? And if you really want to use regexp, see `Pattern.quote` and String concatenation for the rest (eg: `row.split(Pattern.quote(";") + "(?=(....))");`)

Comment: Consider using [Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/), where you can define a custom field and line separators and usage of quotes. In fact, it is extremely easy to use

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I am using Commons CSV for parsing csv file. And I need this to parse header row(which can be any row) of file and pass it to Commons CSV, as there is no way to pass header row index to Commons CSV parser.

Answer (score 3):

[uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) can autodetect the input format to discover what separator/quote character to use:

```
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many options here, check the tutorial.

    // turns on automatic detection of line separators, 
    // column separators, quotes & quote escapes
    settings.detectFormatAutomatically();

    // configures to skip a number of rows from the input and start parsing from there
    settings.setNumberOfRowsToSkip(3);

    // configures the parser to extract headers from the first parsed row
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    List<String[]> rows = parser.parseAll(new File("/path/to/your/file.csv"));
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library, it's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR: Use a CSV parser

This is the only answer that is correct. There is only one way to parse files, and that is with a parser.

Example usage [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) (no affiliation, just my preferred choice):

```
try(final  CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"), '\t', '"', '\'')) {
//                                                ^ your file                ^ delimiter
//                                                                                 ^ quote
//                                                                                       ^ escape char

}
```

This is fully configurable and supports escape sequences, unlike your regex solution.

Comment: actually... OP cannot use  *field separator & text qualifier on the fly*, also a bit of formatting/identation does not kill any puppet ;)

Comment: @JordiCastilla "_passed as input along with csv file_". This is **exactly** what the OP needs. Please re-read the question.

Comment: @JordiCastilla OpenCSV supports that too. The OP has not said exactly how the data is passed in. I think this fully answers the question as it stands.